# Netsuite : HTML/Email Sublist of Transaction not looping correctly

Tags: html-email, netsuite, freemarker

I am looping the transaction.item to get the stockcodes which perfectly works like a charm.

[image]

But when I tried to get the links for individual item, it populates all of the td tag, the link should exist ONLY on stockcode 100132 but instead the rest of the items get the links too. Also I did double check the databse if there were any links for the rest of stockcodes. It only exist on stockcode 100132.

[image]

This is definitely weird and doesnt make any sense to me. Here's my code for the list

```
   <#list transaction.item as sdsitem>
        <tr style="text-align: center">
            <td class="th-border stockcode">${sdsitem.item}</td>
            <td class="th-border sdslink">
              <#if (sdsitem.item.custitemabco_sds_email_link)??>
               <a href="${sdsitem.item.custitemabco_sds_email_link}" 
               target="_blank">Link only exists on stockcode 100132</a>
              </#if> 
            </td>
        </tr>
   </#list>
```

Thank you so much for those who will give a time to help me. I'm a beginner at Netsuite, and will really appreciate the answer. God bless!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem you're seeing can be answered by [Suite Answer 98056](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/98056/). When an item is referenced on a transaction (Purchase/Sales/Work/Transfer Order etc), the fields that are found on the item record can not be directly accessed by using a dot to drill through the item.

Instead, you will need to create a new Transaction Item Field that is sourced from the item record, and the field name you're looking at using i.e. custitemabco_sds_email_link.